# Calculate average of a subset of a vector only when subset values meet a condition in R?

Tags: r, vector, average

I have a daily curve x and I am trying to approximate the average peak and offpeak values of x:
https://ibb.co/Fq1Byzk

I have defined a delta threshold such that when delta is below the threshold value, x will be in the offpeak or peak period. I want to get the average peak value where the average is only of values within x where the delta < threshold. Right now it is averaging out the outliers as well.

```
delta <- matrix(0,24,ncol=1)

for (i in 2:24){
  # i-th element is the i-th hour per day
  delta[i] = x[i,2]-x[i-1,2]
}

# Find hour at which max and min daily values occur
max_threshold = 0.15*max(delta)
min_threshold = 0.15*min(delta)
c <- abs(delta) < max_threshold

t1 <- which(delta>max_threshold)[1]-1 # t1: time index at end of off-peak
t2 <- which.max(delta) + 1 # t2 is time of initial peak
t3 <- which.min(delta)-2 # t3 is time of end peak
t4 <- which.min(delta) # t4 time index of evening off-peak

am <- mean(x[1:t1,2]) # average morning off-peak value
peak <- mean(x[t2:t3,2]) #average peak value
pm <- mean(x[t4:24,2]) # average evening off-peak value
```

```
> dput(x)
structure(list(time = structure(c(1451952000, 1451955600, 1451959200, 
1451962800, 1451966400, 1451970000, 1451973600, 1451977200, 1451980800, 
1451984400, 1451988000, 1451991600, 1451995200, 1451998800, 1452002400, 
1452006000, 1452009600, 1452013200, 1452016800, 1452020400, 1452024000, 
1452027600, 1452031200, 1452034800, 1452038400, 1452042000, 1452045600, 
1452049200, 1452052800, 1452056400, 1452060000, 1452063600, 1452067200, 
1452070800, 1452074400, 1452078000, 1452081600, 1452085200, 1452088800, 
1452092400, 1452096000, 1452099600, 1452103200, 1452106800, 1452110400, 
1452114000, 1452117600, 1452121200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "UTC"), Crow_education_Omer = c(0.019186330898848, 
0.0192706664192825, 0.0182164724138513, 0.018174304653634, 0.019355001939717, 
0.0197345117816722, 0.023951287803397, 0.0323848398468467, 0.0343245568168401, 
0.0378244809148717, 0.0393003525224754, 0.0403545465279066, 0.0405232175687756, 
0.0393425202826927, 0.0398907011655169, 0.0377401453944372, 0.0344932278577091, 
0.0317101556833707, 0.0304872906370705, 0.0297282709531601, 0.0287584124681633, 
0.0252584883701317, 0.0196080085010205, 0.0197345117816722, 0.0194815052203687, 
0.0196080085010205, 0.0184273112149375, 0.0184694789751548, 0.0191441631386307, 
0.019692344021455, 0.025469327171218, 0.0352522475416196, 0.0376136421137855, 
0.0403967142881239, 0.0435592963044175, 0.0433484575033313, 0.0430532831818105, 
0.042968947661376, 0.043306289743114, 0.044655658070066, 0.0424207667785518, 
0.0416195793344241, 0.0382883262772615, 0.03769797763422, 0.0330173562501054, 
0.0281680638251219, 0.0234452746807901, 0.0225597517162278)), row.names = 97:144, class = "data.frame")
```

Also, how would I be able to ggplot both the new simplified curve along with the original curve x on the same graph? I can't seem to melt or rbind() the new curve with reduced number of data points with x since my time column is POSIXCT.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain _I want to get the average peak value where the average is only of values within x where the delta < threshold_ a little bit further? For example: You want to include in `am` only values of `x[1:t1,2]` whose `delta < max_threshold`? What about `min_threshold`?

Comment: so for example, I want my average peak value to include only values from 10:00am to 14:00 because the delta computed between 10:00 to 14:00 is less than my max_threshold value of ~0.002. Right now my average peak value includes everything from t2 to t3. I computed max_threshold and min_threshold as they were intended to determine t2 and t3...but I wasn't sure how to do that so I just set t2 and t3 based on adding 1-2hours from the max and min deltas. Ideally t2 and t3 would be based off of exactly where the delta values exceed the max and min thresholds

Comment: Your delta at `13:00` is about `-0.00118`. That's `< max_threshold` but also `< min_threshold`. Why should this one be included? (Sorry for asking stupid questions, but I don't get the algorithm yet...). At `14:00` delta is `< max_thr` and `> min_thr` again.

Comment: you're absolutely correct. i've revised the c vector above to show absolute value of delta instead. Basically I want to average x between t2 and t3 at indices where abs(delta) < max_thr

Answer (score 1):

This is just a partial solution, since it breaks down for the second day. I named the data.frame `df` instead of `x`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df_obj <- df %>% 
  group_by(day = day(time)) %>%  # group by days
  filter(day == 5) %>%           # filter for day 5
  mutate(
    delta_rev = Crow_education_Omer - lag(
      Crow_education_Omer, 
      default = first(Crow_education_Omer)
      ), # delta between day n and n-1
    delta_for = lead(
      Crow_education_Omer, 
      default = last(Crow_education_Omer)
      ) - Crow_education_Omer, # delta between day n-1 and n
    max_tresh  = 0.15 * max(delta_rev)
    )  %>%
  group_by(grp   = 1 - (abs(delta_rev) < 0.15 * max(delta_rev) | abs(delta_for) < 0.15 * max(delta_for)),
           grp2 = cumsum(grp != lag(grp, default = 0))
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    average = mean(Crow_education_Omer) * 
      (1 - grp) * 
      (abs(first(Crow_education_Omer) - last(Crow_education_Omer)) < max_tresh)
  )
```

First we need to modify your existing data.frame to build up your averages. Based on this calculation, we use `ggplot2` for plotting:

```r
df_obj %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = time, y = Crow_education_Omer)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(color = "sample")) +
  geom_line(data = df_obj[df_obj$average != 0, ], aes(x = time, y = average, color = "average")) +
  xlab("Time") +
  ylab("Value")
```

returns

[image]

But for `day 6` this doesn't work as expected: Changing to `filter(day == 6)` and plotting again returns

[image]

which isn't the expected result. Changing the threshold value to `0.33 * max(delta)` and plotting again creates

[image]

So, perhaps you can build up on this code to create a correct and working solution. Good luck!

A few explanations:

- We build up `delta_rev` and `delta_for`. `delta_rev` equals your `delta`, so for a given row/data point `i` we calculate `df[i,2] - df[i-1,2]`.
- `delta_for` changes this, now we calculate `df[i + 1,2] - df[i,2]` for a given `i`. My idea here is: Using both, `delta_rev` and `delta_for` allows us to look at the preceeding and succeeding points. This gives us more information about the neighbours of a given point and is useful to determine if the point belongs to a group (am, peak, pm).
- The `group_by`-function tries to build up the groups based on the treshhold. `grp` checks, if a data point is `< 0.15 max(delta)`, `grp2` creates a unique grouping number.

There are a few issues:

- Based on this algorithm, there can be more than three groups.
- The `group_by` finds another group between 15:00 and 20:00, we filter it out (that's the `(abs(first(Crow_education_Omer) - last(Crow_education_Omer)) < max_tresh)`-part). I'm not sure, if this is a good solution.
- As stated above, this doesn't return a reasonable plot for day 6. Perhaps geom_point's `df_obj[df_obj$average != 0, ]`-part causes this.

Comment: Hi there, would you be able to explain what is happening in the df_obj code? I am not understanding what is happening after x gets filtered down to day 5 only. What is the delta_for and delta_rev doing?

Comment: I'll add an explanation later.

Comment: @Louise added a few explanations. I missed one thing: Obviously I used lot's of `dplyr`-function/syntax. Hopefully you are firm with it. Especially creating the `delta`'s is very easy with `dplyr` and we avoid using a `for`-loop.